How to add IAM access entries
I am using module "eks" 1 successfully to create an EKS cluster in AWS.
Setting enable_cluster_creator_admin_permissions = true adds the role that I am using to execute the tf plan to "IAM access entries" automatically with the "AmazonEKSClusterAdminPolicy". I am ok with that, but additionally I would like to add more roles with different EKS Access Policies.
I couldn't find where/how to do that.
Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve (I added two manually):

1 https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest

What is the current code you have?

@Marko E please explain what for. I don't have a bug in my code. I don't think it would add any value to the question.

For the purpose of understanding what is currently there. I cannot really guess how and what gets created. Linking the entire module isn't really "reproducible".

I wrote what's there: "module eks" with a link to the docs. You don't need to know what gets created, you need to know what does not - and I have very clearly stated what does not get created. Sorry, but I really don't think what you are asking for would help. Nevertheless, thanks for your attention ..

I figured it out. Had to use access_entries like so:
main.tf
[..]

locals {
  my_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:role/<role>"
}

[..]

module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "20.8.5"

  [..]

  access_entries = {
    my_entry = {
      kubernetes_groups = []
      principal_arn     = local.my_role_arn

      policy_associations = {
        cluster = {
          policy_arn = "arn:aws:eks::aws:cluster-access-policy/AmazonEKSClusterAdminPolicy"
          access_scope = {
            type = "cluster"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  [..]

}

